# Manual authentication with authenticationManager spring boot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to manually authenticate an user, inside a service, with the authenticationManager:

```
Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user,
                    senha,
                    Collections.emptyList()
            ));
```

But every time I get the following exception from said manager:

```
"There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id \"null\""
```

The authenticationManager is beeing imported this way:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

I've already tried to change the password input to {bcrypt}password, to inform the correct passwordEncoder but the error persists, I've also created a BCryptPassword Bean, that's defined inside a config file, just like this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class BeansConfig {
        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

EDIT1: This is the format the password is sent to the authenticationManager:
`{bcrypt}$2a$10$[...]`

EDIT2: As suggested I've implemented the following Bean, inside the same config file as the BCryptPasswordEncoder:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder defaultEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

    DelegatingPasswordEncoder passworEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(
      "bcrypt", encoders);
    passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultEncoder);

    return passworEncoder;
}
```

But the error persists.

For further questions, this is how I've configured my password encoding within the `WebSecurity.java` file :

```
    @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

EDIT4: As proposed I've removed the BCryptPassword bean and set my password encoding to the delegatingPasswordEncoding, like this,

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        this.userDetailsService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
}
```

But now I get the following error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detected a Non-hex character at 1 or 2 position
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex.decode(Hex.java:58) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder.decode(StandardPasswordEncoder.java:106) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
```

My password is, still, beeing sent like this:
`{bcrypt}$2a$10$[...]`

For reference, I'm trying to do this: https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088925/manually-authenticate-user-with-authenticationmanager-throws-illegalargumentexce/75089627#75089627.  Since you are inputting a password with a prefix {bcrypt} you need a DelegationPasswordEncoder. See this link for more details - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-password-storage

Comment: I've edited the post trying to best awnser both responses, if any of you could add any further input, it would be appreciated.

Comment: you do not need 2 password encoders, you can set the default password encoder in `passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches` to the bcrypt if you have passwords with no prefix and for others the other hashmap will determine the encoder to use using the password prefix... so you should remove the BCryptPasswordEncoder  bean config and set the delegating password encoder bean in ur auth manager builder.. try and let us know..

Comment: @Neeraj, I've tried what you told me, but now I get a new exception thrown, if you've faced it in the past or know how to solve it, I would appreciate a lot if you could help me.

Comment: When you say - password is being sent like {bcrypt}*** do you mean the user is inputting password like that? Just to double check the way it should be - password in db is like {bcrypt}***and user inputs password normally e.g. pass123..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was debugging I found out that the authenticationManager was using a DaoAuthenticationProvider that contained the wrong passwordEncoder. Defining a Bean of a custom DaoAuthenticationProvider like so:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    return authProvider;
}
```

And setting my AuthenticationManagerBuilder like so:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}
```

Inside the WebSecurity.java configuration file solved all my problems.

Reference: [Custom Authentication Provider](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-authentication-providers/)